# MySQL: Grouping values into several fields as a list

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm facing with the following problem in a MySQL database: Given a join table, where values with different types are connected to a value. The number of Types are fix. Something like this:

```
ID|Type|Value|
---------------
1 | A   | Z   |
1 | A   | X   |
1 | B   | Y   |
2 | A   | Z   |
2 | A   | X   |
```

I have to produce the following result without loops:

```
ID|Type A|Type B|
-----------------
1 | Z,X   | Y    |
2 | Z,X   | NULL |
```

Is it possible?
What I have made is an SQL select using the GROUP_CONCAT command, but it produces something different:

```
select ID, TYPE, group_concat(VALUE) groups from MYTABLE group by ID, TYPE;
```

And it produced

```
ID|TYPE|groups|
-----------------
1 | A   | Z,X  |
1 | B   | Y    |
2 | A   | Z,X  |
```

And I cannot step forward....
What am I doing wrong?
Please help!

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level/ presentation layer - assuming you have that. To my ming, and to a rough approximation, there is not question in MySQL for which GROUP_CONCAT is the answer! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `GROUP_CONCAT` that way will give you all the values in the column `VALUE` into only one column, but you are looking for two columns one for each `TYPE` value.

Use the `CASE` expression inside the `GROUP_CONCAT` so that you got a column for each type, something like this:

```
SELECT
  ID, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'A' THEN VALUE END) AS 'Type A',
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'B' THEN VALUE END) AS 'Type B'
FROM yourtable 
GROUP BY ID;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e14afc/12)